# Add Number sequence afterwards based on this Group and Order

Tags: apex, aggregateresult, number

I need some help with the following. After the collection of different records across Salesfore, a set of new invoice records is created like the example below

This list is Grouped by Invoice number and Ordered by Header.
There is always a Header (H) and pairs of positive and negative lines (X). H is the sum of X per Group.

Example:

[image]

I’d like to number this list of records afterwards based on this Group and Order. The result should be like this.

[image]

I think I can catch this records with

AggregateResult[] addNumber =   [SELECT InvoiceNumber, Header FROM myObject
WHERE objectId IN :myObjectId
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber, Header,
ORDER BY Header ASC];

But then what!?
I am really looking forward to anyone’s reaction.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: How are the records inserted? i.e. are they inserted as a complete Invoice, i.e. all H and X lines present?

Comment: Hello Phil, thank you for reaching out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first (positive) X record is created after collection a single record in another object and is created again with a Fee calculated *-1 so that a negative X record is also present. There can be 2 or 100 pairs. H is created after that to collect all the revenues.

Comment: Then it would seem to make sense to create the invoice line numbers after the H record is created because at this point you have all H and X records and thus can number them as illustrated

Comment: Thanks again, Phil. But the point is that it now numbers from 1 to 15. It takes all records and is ignoring the GROUP BY.